# howto neatly modify a PE's datssection

Tags: c, winapi, portable-executable

I'm writing a dll in 'C/C++ - Win32API' environment.
I have some constant variables (all are DWORD values and LPWSTR/LPSTR strings) that I have to enable the user modify. 
what I'm looking for is (hopefully)  a tool that enable a SAFE binary modification as described, 
in a way that updates all the necessary tables of the PE.

Comment: Read them from an external config file, and let the user modify that?

Comment: Impossible in my scenario, the binary have to be completely self-contained.

Comment: Does your "self-contained" requirement allow use of the registry?

Comment: This is usually a bad idea, but there are many approaches to do it.  You could put the data in resources.  There are Windows APIs and several free tools for editing the resources of compiled binaries.  Alternatively, you can export the data (much as you export functions) so that a separate tool (that you write yourself) can locate the data and overwrite it with new values.  Or you could put the data in its own PE section - this might contain a single struct with all your constants and *offsets* to the subsequent string data.  This can easily be overwritten by a separate utility.

Comment: arx, can you please detail about the last method of creating a separate PE section?

Comment: hey michael I missed your comment, but no , registry is not an option. thanks.

Comment: This is what resources are for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a struct in a separate PE section thus:

```
// Create the section
#pragma section("myconst", read)

// Declare a struct to hold the constant data
typedef struct
{
    DWORD a;
    DWORD b;
    char stringa[256];
    char stringb[256];
} ConstData;

// Create an initialized instance of the struct in the new section
__declspec(allocate("myconst"))
const ConstData theData = {0xdeadbeef, 0xfeedface, "Hello", "dolly"};
```

Compile the code.  Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt, run

```
dumpbin /all myexe.exe > dump.txt
notepad dump.txt
```

Search for the `myconst` section.  You should see something like:

```
SECTION HEADER #4
 myconst name
     208 virtual size
    4000 virtual address (00404000 to 00404207)
     400 size of raw data
    2000 file pointer to raw data (00002000 to 000023FF)
       0 file pointer to relocation table
       0 file pointer to line numbers
       0 number of relocations
       0 number of line numbers
40000040 flags
         Initialized Data
         Read Only

RAW DATA #4
  00404000: EF BE AD DE CE FA ED FE 48 65 6C 6C 6F 00 00 00  ï¾­ÞÎúíþHello...
  00404010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
  00404020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
```

You can see the two hex values that were initialised in the code and the first string value.  You can also see that the offset of this data in the PE file - "file pointer to raw data" - is 0x2000.

Armed with that information it is very easy to construct a new data block, open the PE file and overwrite the data at 0x2000.

To determine the offset from code you need to parse the PE file header and section headers.  This is fairly straightforward.  Or you could grab the offset from the dumpbin output as part of your build process, and feed it into the build of the editing tool.

Note that to test this in release mode you need to actually make use of `theData` or the linker will throw it away.  Also note that the section only has the `read` attribute so it is truly read-only.  Attempting to write it will give an access violation.

And finally...  This is all quite scruffy.  I wouldn't bother unless you really have no alternative.

Comment: arx, thank you so much!  it's exactly what I meant and needed.

Comment: Something occurred to me: The struct instance is const so the optimizer could conceivably "inline" the constant values.  If it did then changing the PE wouldn't change the effective constant values.  You need to test to ensure this hasn't happened.  If it does, make sure the struct is in its own translation unit, then try removing the const and then turning off whole program optimization.